# How to order by first record of another order by result?

Tags: mysql, select

I am trying to create my own messaging like with SMS in phones.

I have a MySQL table like this

```
id                  (the message id)
from_member_id      (the id of the member who sent this message)
to_member_id        (the id of the member who the message was sent to)
date sent           (the date it was sent)
active              (if this message is deleted or active)
text                (the text)
```

And I want to get the information in a special ordered way.

First it has to be sorted by the id that's not you (call it 'other' id). Then for each section of that ordering, it needs get the top most record (which should be the most recent date), and then sort the sections by the date value of that record.

I can do the first ordering by this:

```
SELECT
  from_member_id,
  to_member_id,
  (CASE WHEN from_member_id = ? THEN to_member_id ELSE from_member_id END CASE) AS conversation_member_id,
  date_sent
FROM table
WHERE from_member_id = ?
OR to_member_id = ?
ORDER BY conversation_member_id DESC, date_sent DESC
```

where the `?` is my id.

But the problem is how to do the second ordering, where I need to order the sections by the date of the top record (which should be most recent date). Note when I say section, I mean the group of records with the same 'other' id.

Does anyone know how to do this?

Thanks.

**EDIT:**

Example

If my id is 5:

```
From To   Date
5     6   july 28
6     5   july 7
6     5   july 7
5     2   july 26
5     2   july 26
2     5   july 26
```

So the july 28 date should come on top, because it happened the most recently even though there are dates in that section that are before july 26.

So when I do the first ordering, it orders by the other id, which would be the 6, and then 2. The ones with 6 is one section, and the ones with 2 is the second section.

Comment: I am not following you.  Can you give an example of the desired output?

Comment: ok I added an example of the output. It has been ordered by 'other' id, so the other id would be 6 and 2, so all the record with 6 is grouped, and the records with 2 is grouped (so 2 sections). Then it is ordered by date for each section. Then it is ordered by the date of the first record of each section (which should be the most recent date), so july 28 is more recent than july 26 so it appears on top.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm an MS SQL guy, but I trust this is clear enough:

```
CREATE TABLE #Messages
(
FromID  INT NOT NULL,
ToID    INT NOT NULL,
Date    DATETIME2(0) NOT NULL,
Text    VARCHAR(200) NOT NULL
)
INSERT INTO #Messages (FromID, ToID, Date, Text) VALUES
    (5, 6, '2013-07-28 12:00', 'A'),
    (6, 5, '2013-07-07 02:00', 'B'),
    (6, 5, '2013-07-07 01:00', 'C'),
    (5, 2, '2013-07-26 03:00', 'D'),
    (5, 2, '2013-07-26 02:00', 'E'),
    (2, 5, '2013-07-26 01:00', 'F')

DECLARE @Me INT = 5
SELECT
    M.FromID, M.ToID, M.Date, M.Text
FROM
    #Messages AS M
    INNER JOIN
        (
        SELECT
            CASE WHEN FromID = @Me THEN ToID ELSE FromID END AS ID,
            MAX(Date) AS MostRecentDate
        FROM
            #Messages
        GROUP BY
            CASE WHEN FromID = @Me THEN ToID ELSE FromID END
        ) AS Seq ON CASE WHEN M.FromID = @Me THEN M.ToID ELSE M.FromID END = Seq.ID
ORDER BY
    Seq.MostRecentDate DESC, M.Date DESC
```

Comment: That's super complex to me lol. I may just do that last ordering in my android app after getting the data. I think it might be more efficient doing it in java than in sql.

Comment: It might be easier for you to program, but aggregation is almost always faster in SQL than in general purpose programming languages.  I recommend you learn a little SQL, it's very good at what it does.